# Biblatex encoding

Tags: biblatex, input-encodings

I've got a large document which I wrote some time ago. It contains a bibliography for which I use `biblatex`:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxnames=1, doi=false, url=false, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
```

For the encoding within the LaTeX-document, I use:

```
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Last time I was working with the document (around a month ago), the encoding of bibliography items was not a problem and special characters were displayed in a correct way, e.g. the author name "Brydøy". However, now, it's only displayed as "BrydÃ¸y". If I simply put "Brydøy" into the normal text, it is displayed properly, but within the citations (in text citation as well as the bibliography) there seems to be something wrong with the encoding. I would appreciate help on how to fix this issue very much.

Comment: Try using `backend=biber` instead of `bibtex8`. Do you know what encoding your bib file is in?

Comment: @AlanMunn That's what I've been trying just before I saw your comment. :-) However, `backend=biber` doesn't help either. I export the references into the bib-file from EndNote, so I guess it should be in Unicode.

Comment: You can specify the `bibencoding` explicitly as a `biblatex` option. See section 2.4.3.4 of the `biblatex` manual. Also, if you make a small UTF-8 encoded document, does the `.bib` file work correctly (with `backend=biber` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`)?

Comment: @AlanMunn Setting `bibencoding=utf8` solved the problem (I didn't change `\usepackage[ansinew]inputenc`, though). Thanks a lot! If you'd put your comment as an answer, I will set it as accepted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

File encodings are not always easily determined, and so `biblatex` sometimes needs some help in deciding on the encoding of the bib file, especially if your bib file is encoded differently from your input file. But you can specify the bib file encoding directly as a `biblatex` option.  If your bib file is UTF-8 encoded, you will need to use `biber` as the backend.

So you should load `biblatex` this way:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, ... ]{biblatex}
```

(where ... is any other `biblatex` options.)

See section 2.4.3.4 of the `biblatex` manual for more details on bib file encoding issues.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may not be what you're looking for, but you might give it a try.

In order to avoid any complication with special characters in my .bib file (or any of my tex files in fact), I usually use the code for the special char. I belive in the case of `Brydøy`, it would be `Bryd\o{}y`.

Comment: I added an empty group (`{}`) after `\o`. You are correct that `\o` produces an ø, but `\oy` will not work.

Comment: @wiwh, TorbjørnT. : The problem is that I already have a large .bib-file (246 entries at the moment) and it would take me a lot of time to go through all author names and to change the special characters. Furthermore, since I manage my bibliography with EndNote and subsequently export it to BibTeX format, I would need to change the characters within the EndNote library which would look weird and wouldn't be appropriate in case I would use this library in future for other document types rather than LaTeX.

Comment: @AnjaM A simple find and replace would make it fairly quick to fix, but I agree that it isn't an ideal solution. (I didn't write this answer, by the way.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry, I noticed that it wasn't your answer only after submitting my comment.