# BibLaTeX Biber in TeXnicCenter does not produce bibliography

Tags: biblatex, texniccenter, biber

I recently changed to `backend=biber` after some problems with encoding in `bibtex8` ( [Biblatex encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52873/biblatex-encoding) ). Everything seemed to work fine until I added some references and updated the bibliography file. The new references remained undefined. I removed all "additional" files (like `.aux` etc.) from the project folder and ran LaTeX three times. All the references were now undefined and even no `.blg` file is produced. So I had a look in the internet and found someone with a similar problem in a German LaTeX community. He used to work with Texmaker, and apparently the problem was that `biber` was trying to get the information from `.aux` file instead of `.bcf` file. That user changed this manually in Texmaker and everything started working. However, another user suggested that within TeXnicCenter (which I am using) this doesn't need to be done as this is already indicated by `%tm`. Now I am completely lost as to how to fix the problem.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxnames=1, doi=false, url=false, bibencoding=utf8, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\bibliography{litthesis}

\begin{document}

This is my text \parencite{Hong2006}

\newpage

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And here is the bibliography:

```
@article{Hong2006,
author = {Hong, Seungpyo and Leroueil, Pascale R and Janus, Elizabeth K and Peters, Jennifer L and Kober, Mary-Margaret and Islam, Mohammad T and Orr, Bradford G and Baker, James R and Holl, Mark M Banaszak},
title = {Interaction of polycationic polymers with supported lipid bilayers and cells: nanoscale hole formation and enhanced membrane permeability.},
journal = {Bioconjug Chem},
volume = {17},
number = {3},
pages = {728-734},
year = {2006}
}
```

Here is what's written in the `.log`-file:

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'mwe.bbl' not found.

No file mwe.bbl.
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: You have to run Biber.

Comment: @egreg Well, how do I do this in TeXnicCenter?

Comment: It is completely impossible that biber is trying to get information from the .aux file. It ignores the .aux file. When you tell biblatex you are using biber with "backend=biber" (or no option at all, in upcoming biblatex 2.0), it writes a special .bcf XML file which biber uses to get its information.

Comment: @PLK Well, I just repeated what a member of another community wrote that helped him. Anyway, the problem still remains that `biber` fails to produce bibliography, and this problem seems not only to occur for me. Do you have any idea why this happens? `backend=bibtex8` works fine in this respect, so it shouldn't be a problem of the `.bib` file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As we found out on [golatex.de](http://www.golatex.de/biber-erstellt-keine-bibliographie-t8738.html) the problem is quite similar to the one in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47553/5049) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18859/5049).

`biber` was complaining:

```
data source C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\par-416e6a61\cache-46f2da95c5284272f49f4e60b997c7e3f24afb19\recode_data.xml not found in . 
Compilation failed in require at Biber/Utils.pm line 21. 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber/Utils.pm line 21. 
Compilation failed in require at Biber/Utils.pm line 8. 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber/Utils.pm line 8. 
Compilation failed in require at (eval 24) line 2. 
...propagated at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/base.pm line 94. 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber.pm line 5. 
Compilation failed in require at script/biber-MSWIN line 17. 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script/biber-MSWIN line 17.
```

The solution [suggested by @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47558/5049) and [@pmav99, resp.,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18868/5049) to the other questions -- namely deleting the `par-<some string>` directory in the temporary folder -- solved the issue here as well.