# Biblatex not reading .bib file contents

Tags: biblatex, texmaker

Apologies if this is answered elsewhere, but I've been searching message boards for hours and tinkering with fixes... it seems to me that I have a problem with my MiKTeX / TexMakerX installation.

I have just installed the most recent installation of MiKTeX (64bit version) and `biblatex`, and manually placed the most recent `biber.exe` in the MiKTeX `/bin` folder.

My `bibtex` command is set in TexMakerX as

```
"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/biber.exe" %
```

And my "quick build" function is set to `pdflatex - bibtex - pdflatex - pdflatex`.

I've been testing with the biblatex samples (I'll just call it `sample.tex`, with `biblatex-examples.bib` downloaded in the same folder) from
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples

Invoking `pdflatex` THEN `bibtex` generates the following errors

```
warning - no file sample.aux
warning - no file sample.bbl
--a whole bunch of undefined citation errors--
warning - empty bibliography on input line 51 %whereever \printbibliography is placed
warning - file 'sample.out' has changed
warning - there were undefined references
please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) sample(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards
```

Running `biber` as requested through a command window generates:

```
data source ....(long path out of Temp folder)...\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found.
Compilation failed in require at Biber/Utils.pm line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber/Uutils.pm line 20.
Compilation failed in require at Biber/Utils.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber/Uutils.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 24) line 2.
     ...propagated at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/base.pm line 94.
BEGIN failed--compilation abobrted at Biber.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at script.biber-MSWIN line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script.biber-MSWIN line 17.
```

So... there seems to be no communication between the local `.bib` file and the `latex`/`biblatex` system.  And I'm clueless on what to do after all this tinkering...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your problem has already been addressed: remove the directory related to `biber` in the `Temp` folder. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54545/4427

Comment: Do you have `backend=bibtex` as an option of `biblatex when you use `bibtex?

Comment: It looks like you need to delete your biber cache and re-run it. On the command-line run `biber --cache` and delete the folder it reports.