# How to automate biber within TeXnicCenter?

Tags: biber, texniccenter

I am trying to automate my LaTeX pdf output within TeXnicCenter. I am using `pdflatex` with `biber` and it's been proposed to get the following settings:

[image]

However, whenever I add a new `\autocite{xyz}` in my document, TeXnicCenter outputs an error: Citation xyz not found.

When I rerun `biber` manually, with `biber file.bcf` and recompile with `pdflatex` it works.

How can I automate my process, to just compile and recompile from within TeXnicCenter?

Note: My problem is NOT being discussed or solved with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53959/biblatex-biber-in-texniccenter-does-not-produce-bibliography/54545#54545) question.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working or non working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. I'm using Biber without any problems on TC 2 Beta

Comment: @percuße: Which setting do you use? A MWE seems too complex for this problem as its not connected to data.

Comment: Have you ever tried latexmk? It’s a perl script (available from CTAN, included in MiKTeX) that automatically determines what needs to be run and does it. I’ve used it with Biber, and it works with a bunch of other things as well. Also, the maintainer is really responsive and answers questions here. So in your case, you’d just call `latexmk -pdf foo.tex`. Basically, the automation you’re trying to achieve has already been implemented with a general solution.

Comment: Just a small example to show that the citation doesn't work is sufficient. No need to include all the details.

Comment: For a code piece for a bibliography MWE, see this answer of mine to [I&#39;ve just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Answer (score 3):

Because you gave no MWE it is more a guess what happend.

With your given profile you have to choose in TeXnicCenter the proper profile `LaTeX = PDF(BIBER)` in the white field below menu point `format`. If you then compile twice a complete MWE, using package `biblatex` with option `backend=biber` (important, I guess this is missing!), everything should work.

Try this MWE:

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97218/how-to-automate-biber-within-texniccenter
\listfiles                % shows used packages in a list in log file
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author2000,
  author  = {AuthorA},
  title   = {Title of Article},
  journal = {Name of Journal},
  year    = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear
 ,backend=biber         % to force biblatex to use biber
 ,sortlocale=de_DE
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}              % all bib entrys are printed

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Try this MWE on your computer (store it for example as file `mb-biber.tex` with utf8 coding) and compile it twice. If you still have errors (there should only be one correct warning caused by `filecontents`) please edit your question and add the error messages you get. Add also the list of used packages near the end of your `log` file.

I hope this answer helps you to see how important it is to show us what you are doing. That's the reason for comments asking for a MWE.