# How to use biber with keywords

Tags: biblatex, biber

When I try to compile references with keywords with `biber`

```
%adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97218/how-to-automate-biber-within-texniccenter
\listfiles                % shows used packages in a list in log file
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author2000,
  author  = {AuthorA},
  title   = {Title of Article},
  journal = {Name of Journal},
  year    = {2000},
  keywords = {Key},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear
 ,backend=biber         % to force biblatex to use biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Hello \nocite{*}              % all bib entrys are printed

\printbibliography[keyword=Key]

\end{document}
```

But it always fails:

```
>biber texmwe
INFO - This is Biber 1.7
INFO - Logfile is 'texmwe.blg'
INFO - Reading 'texmwe.bcf'
WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.0, expected version 2.5
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'texmwe.bib' for section 0
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\par-646572617269\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 119.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\par-646572617269\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 123.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\par-646572617269\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 127.
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'texmwe.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'English_United States.1252' default tailoring 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'nyt' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'English_United States.1252'
Can't use string ("Key") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at C:\Users\derari\AppData\Local\Temp\par-646572617269\cache-c3e641bac9e7e4b5ab17068122bff38686710985\inc\lib/Biber/Output/bbl.pm line 436.
```

It works with bibtex, except that it complains about unsupported utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Your biblatex version is too old for biber 1.7. You need biblatex 2.7.

Comment: With an current MiKTeX 2.9 your MWE compiles after 3 runs without problems. Can you add the result of `\listfiles` to your question? BTW: I think @UlrikeFischer is right ...

Comment: I only tried updating with MiKTeX' update tool before, but a full reinstall did the trick. Thanks, you can add this as an answer if you wish.

Comment: @Arian: In a multiuser installation you must run the update tool in user *and* admin mode.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it the problem is caused by an out-of-date installation