# Bibliography, biblatex

Tags: biblatex

this MWE used to output a bibliography and a list of mateiral but does no longer work. I get this error, when compiling: `Package keyval Error: publisher undefined`. Any help appreciated!

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,headings=normal,headsepline=true,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nty,style=verbose,isbn=false,url=false,publisher=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
    @INCOLLECTION{Doe1999,
      author = {John Doe},
      title = {Title of Book},
      publisher = {Kluwer Law International},
      year = {1999},
      volume = {25},
      series = {Series},
      shortauthor = {Doe},
            \begin{flushleft}

            \end{flushleft}

      shorttitle = {Title of Book}
    }
    @MISC{DoeJ,
    author={Jane Doe},
    title={Title of misc},
    keyword={mat},
    shortauthor={Doe J},
    shorttitle={Misc}
    }
    \end{filecontents}
            \renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    \renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
    \defbibheading{lit}{\chapter*{Literaturverzeichnis}}
    \defbibheading{mat}{\chapter*{Materialienverzeichnis}}

    \DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,shorttitle,journal]{title}{#1}
    \renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
        \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}
        \iffieldundef{shorthand}{%
            \ifciteseen{%
                \usebibmacro{cite:short}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    \renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
        \printnames{shortauthor}%
        \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
        \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
        \printfield{shorttitle}}}%
    \renewbibmacro*{finentry}{
                    \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
                    {
                        \iffieldundef{shorttitle}{%
                        \adddot}{
                        \printtext[parens]{%
                        {cit.}\addspace
                        \printfield{shorttitle}%
                        }\adddot
                        }
                    }
                    {
                        \iffieldundef{shorttitle}
                        {
                            \printtext[parens]{%
                            {cit.}\addspace
                            \printnames{shortauthor}%
                            }\adddot
                        }
                        {
                            \printtext[parens]{%
                            {cit.}\addspace
                            \printnames{shortauthor}\addcomma\addspace
                            \printfield{shorttitle}%
                            }\adddot
                        }
                    }
                    \finentry}
    \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
        \printlist{location}{\addspace}%
        \printfield{year}{\setunit*{\addspace}}%
    }
    \renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
        \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct{\addspace}}%
            \newunit%
        \printlist{institution}{\addspace}%
        \printlist{location}{\addspace}%
        \printfield{year}{\setunit*{\addspace}}%
    }
    \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{publisher}}
    %\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}
    %\ifpunct{\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}}{}
    \addbibresource{MWE.bib}
    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \printbibliography[title={Lit},heading=lit,notkeyword=mat]
    \printbibliography[title={Mat},heading=mat,keyword=mat]
    \mainmatter
    Lorem ipsum\footcite[p. 1]{Doe1999}\footcite[p. 2]{DoeJ}.
    \backmatter
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is somewhat far away from being a minimal (!) working example. Please reduce it to the amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. For some hints to accomplish this have a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228

Comment: Voting to close as _too localized_. You’ve been pointed to our [MWE Question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) several times in the past, yet you keep including entirely irrelevant things like a font package or `geometry`. You can still edit your question, and we can reopen it if you turn your code into a proper MWE.

Comment: Omit `publisher=false` in your load-time option settings for biblatex. `publisher` isn't an option for any of the standard styles.

Comment: This is not a help forum, but a question and answer site, so we will close this one. If it would be edited to be a good question useful for the public, i.e. not just a "this long code doesn't work, please help", we would gladly reopen.

Comment: Thx for comments, tried to trim my question... thanks very much to Audrey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audrey's solution solved the first part of my problem.

However, the bibliography would still not appear in the pdf file.

Turnes out I had to delete the cache files in \user\AppData\Local\Temp (Windows 8), recompile and voilà. This problem seems to be addressed in this post (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54545/19581). However, I did not understand why this problem persists.